# How to limit speed downloading file in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, download

I have read this article on Codeproject, but I don't know how to apply it to asp.net MVC 3
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18243/Bandwidth-throttling

Here is the code for downloading a file in my project

```
public ActionResult GetFile(int id)
{
    var f = FileAcc.GetInfo(id);
    var templateStr = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(f.file_url), FileMode.Open);
    return File(templateStr, f.file_name);
}
```

Please support me on this issue; thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include `ThrottledStream.cs` in your project and replace your GetFile method with the following -

```
public ActionResult GetFile(int id) {
    var f = FileAcc.GetInfo(id);
        int bufferSize = 1024, bps = 1024;
        using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(f.file_url), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize)) {
            using (Born2Code.Net.ThrottledStream destinationStream = new Born2Code.Net.ThrottledStream(Response.OutputStream, bps)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int readCount = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                Response.Buffer = false;
                while (readCount > 0) {
                    destinationStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                    readCount = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
            }
        }
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

And tweak bps per your need.